# Scrapy Scrape element within unknown number of <div>

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a list of website on [Shopee](https://shopee.com.my/). Some example include [dudesgadget](https://dudesgadgets.com/products/happy-birthday-sign-3d-led-lamp) and [2ubest](https://www.2ubest.com/products/hot-selling-lovely-tea-infuser-pug?variant=44172377813). Each of these shopee shop have different design and way of constructing their web element and different domain as well. They looks like stand alone website but they are actually not.

So the main problem here is I am trying to scrape the product details. I will summarize some different structure:

**2ubest**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="shopify-section-announcement-bar" id="shopify-section-announcement-bar">
            <main class="wrapper main-content" role="main">
                <div class="grid">
                    <div class="grid__item">
                        <div id="shopify-section-product-template" class="shopify-section">
                            <script id="ProductJson-product-template" type="application/json">
                                //Things I am looking for
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**littleplayland**](https://www.littleplayland.com/products/adjustable-ergonomic-mobile-laptop-stand)

```
<html>
    <body id="adjustable-ergonomic-laptop-stand" class="template-product">
        <script>
            //Things I am looking for
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And few other, and I had discover a pattern between them.

1. The thing that I am looking for will for sure in `<body>`
2. The thing that I am looking for is within a `<script>`
3. The only thing that I not sure is the distance from `<body>` to `<script>`

My solution is:

```
def parse(self, response):
    body = response.xpath("//body")
    for script in body.xpath("//script/text()").extract():
        #Manipulate the script with js2xml here
```

I am able to extract the [littleplayland](https://www.littleplayland.com/products/adjustable-ergonomic-mobile-laptop-stand), [dailysteals](https://www.dailysteals.com/products/emoji-pillows-various-styles) and many others which has very less distance from the `<body>` to `<script>`, but does not works for the [2ubest](https://www.2ubest.com/products/hot-selling-lovely-tea-infuser-pug?variant=44172377813) which has a lot of other html element in between to the thing I am looking for. Can I know are there solution that I can ignore all the html element in between and only look for the `<script>` tag?

I need a single solution that are generic and can work across all [Shopee](https://shopee.com.my/) website if possible since all of them have the characteristic that I had mention above.

**Which mean that the solution should not filter using `<div>` because every different website have different numbers of `<div>`**

Comment: `body.xpath("//script/text()")` should give you all `<script>` in HTML - if it wasn't added by JavaScript.

Comment: The thing is when it had too manyy `<div>` in between then it return me nothing. It only return me something when the depth of `<div>` is very few. The depth limit by default is 0, which is not limit, but not sure why it stop at `x` number of html tag depth

Comment: If you realize, the `script` in the `for loop` is already the `text()` from `<script>` if any, but it return nothing is the problem when html tag depth too high

Comment: it shouldn't have problem with any depth. The only problem which I saw in other tools was when it was inside `<iframe>` tag because code inside `<iframe>` is separated page/file.

Comment: maybe you should precise what is inside this `<script>` so we could check  it in HTML.

Comment: I know what is the problem, it doesn't return me any value because when I put the data I want into `js2xml.parse(data)`, it gives me exception which i handle and straight pass to the next iteration which making it seems like nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to get the scripts in your HTML using Scrapy:

```
scriptTagSelector = scrapy.Selector(text=text, type="html")
theScripts = scriptTagSelector.xpath("//script/text()").extract()

for script in theScripts:
    #Manipulate the script with js2xml here
    print("------->A SCRIPT STARTS HERE<--------")
    print(script)
    print("------->A SCRIPT ENDS HERE<--------")
```

Here is an example with the HTML in your question (I added an extra script :) ):

```
import scrapy

text="""<html>
    <body>
        <div id="shopify-section-announcement-bar" id="shopify-section-announcement-bar">
            <main class="wrapper main-content" role="main">
                <div class="grid">
                    <div class="grid__item">
                        <div id="shopify-section-product-template" class="shopify-section">
                            <script id="ProductJson-product-template" type="application/json">
                                //Things I am looking for
                            </script>
                        </div>
                        <script id="script 2">I am another script</script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>"""

scriptTagSelector = scrapy.Selector(text=text, type="html")
theScripts = scriptTagSelector.xpath("//script/text()").extract()

for script in theScripts:
    #Manipulate the script with js2xml here
    print("------->A SCRIPT STARTS HERE<--------")
    print(script)
    print("------->A SCRIPT ENDS HERE<--------")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//body//script/text()
```